# Button click event triggered by enter key ... why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Error = "";

        //Any attempt to login from another page met with an error is bounced here.  We then display the error message.  We do this because many other pages have a css dropdown with limited options and no warning label.
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try { Error = Session["LoginError"].ToString(); }
            catch { }
            Session["LoginError"] = "";


            //  if (Error.Length > 0) { WarningLbl.Text = Error; }
            LoadPageText();

        }
        else
        {

            Enroll();


        }
    }
```

on PostBack, when I press enter ... Enroll(); executes, but it also executes the following button_event

this is the ASP

```
<td style="width: 75px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="FrenchBtn" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" BorderStyle="None" CssClass="clickable" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="White" OnClick="FrenchBtn_Click" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'white';" onmouseover="this.style.color = 'yellow';" Text="Button" />
                                                </td>
```

here is the CSS:

```
.clickable {
            z-index: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

protected void FrenchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SessionVars.Current.varLanguage = "French";
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Enroll.aspx");
    }
```

Note: I have not pressed the button to execute this; however, this is the first "clickable" event on the screen. Why is this executing? is there some attribute or property or sequence that is causing this to execute?

Comment: Do you have a Page.Form.DefaultButton set?

Comment: If the DefaultButton is not set, it is probably just the browser doing that for you. Would switching to a LinkButton help?

Comment: I am going run this in another Browser like Chrome and see. Thanks

Comment: I corrected the issue by setting my other button "EnrollBtn" to the default button, so now when you press enter ... it does the Enroll process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called form's default submit button. Make sure it isn't registered within the form or somewhere else on the page (check containers where you button is placed in, pages and panels have this functionality)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="FrenchBtn">
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/229011/How-to-make-a-button-the-default-button-on-enter

Comment: no I do not have that: <form id="form1" runat="server">

Comment: it can also be done in the code, have a look at the code behind your panels(if any) or page code itself

Comment: thank you Andrew ... I am not finding any of those conditions, i didn't write this piece of code so I must be missing something somewhere

Comment: You mean Javascript ... there is none

Comment: Look on the Master Page. You most likely have a form with `runat="server"` somewhere. You can use Visual Studio's Find feature to search for it (Press Control-F).

Comment: I corrected the issue by making the main "submit" button the default button, so now when I press enter ... "submit or in my case "enroll" is called. Thanks so much